# Parsing ps and grep output in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cgi

I get the following message when I do a "ps -ef | grep port"

```
apache    6215     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 perl /scripts/myscript.pl -sn 4123E -sku HSME01-HW -port 8
```

Is there a way to parse the following:

- start time (11:20)
- sn (4123E)
- sku (HSME01-HW)
- port (8)

Comment: The "grep" shouldn't be in title, but that's no reason to -1 a newbie instead of answering his question!

Comment: It is more a question of 'how many different ways are there to parse the output' than 'is there a way to do it'.

Comment: You might find `ps -eo start_time,args` a bit easier to parse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `awk` for both filtering and parsing:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[p]ort/ {printf "start time: %s\nsn: %s\nsku: %s\nport: %s\n", $5, $11, $13, $NF}'
```

As glenn jackman pointed out in the comments the square brackets in the filter string prevent the expression from matching the filter string itself in the process list.

Comment: Since that may also pick the awk command from the ps output, use `/[p]ort/` to filter

Comment: Thanks Ansgar.  Could someone explain to me what the $5, $11, $13, $NF mean or correspond to?

Comment: @Jeremy `awk` automatically splits input lines into fields (default separator is whitespace). These fields can be accessed via variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. `$NF` is a special variable with the value of the last field of an input line (NF for "Number of Fields"). In your case you could also use `$15`, but sometimes it's more convenient if you don't need to know the actual number of fields beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question is tagged as `bash`, using bash-only solutions (no awk or perl) is preferred...

```
LINE='apache    6215     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 perl /scripts/myscript.pl -sn 4123E -sku HSME01-HW -port 8'

## Convert string to bash array
ARR=($LINE)

echo "start time (${ARR[4]})"
echo "sn (${ARR[10]})"
echo "sku (${ARR[12]})"
echo "port (${ARR[14]})"

## How to save the value?
START_TIME=${ARR[4]}
```

Comment: I realize this post was years ago, however, as a new guy, I'm wondering how to parse multiple results from ps, as in the case of processes like cups or sshd for instance, and not just "LINE=apache...etc" as above. TIA

Comment: @endorpheus You can parse one line at a time, right? (with `| while read LINE`) I'm not sure what output you get from cups or sshd. Perhaps you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: No need, you answered my question, thank you, @saeedgnu